# @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) lazy loading not working

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

I am working with JPA 2.1 (EclipseLink 2.5.1) and JBoss 7.1.

I've define very simple JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APLICACIONES_TB")
public class Aplicacion implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name="COD_APLICACION_V")
  private long codAplicacionV;

  @Column(name="APLICACION_V")
  private String aplicacionV;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="aplicacion")
  private Collection<Prestacion> prestaciones;

  ... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PRESTACIONES_TB")
public class Prestacion implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name="COD_PRESTACIONES_V")
  private String codPrestacionesV;

  @Column(name="DESCRIPCION_V")
  private String descripcionV;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "COD_APLICACION_V")    
  private Aplicacion aplicacion;

  ... getters and setters ...
}
```

I have developed a staless EJB that executes a query to obtain some "Aplicacion" entities.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DocuEJB implements DocuEJBLocal
{
  @PersistenceContext(name="DocuEjb", type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  private EntityManager em;

  public Prestacion getResult(String name)
  {
    return em.createNamedQuery("ExampleQueryName", Prestacion.class).getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

Because I'm working with JSF 2.1 the EJB is being injected in a managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ManagedBean
{   
  @EJB DocuEJB docuEjb;

  public String doSomething()
  {
     Prestacion entity = docuEjb.getResult("egesr");

     if (entity != null)
     {
        // It should return null because 'entity' should be detached
        Aplicacion app = entity.getAplicacion();

        // but 'app' entity is not null, ¿why not?
        System.out.println (app.getCodAplicacionV());
     }
  }
}
```

Lazy loading is not working even when lazy loading has been defined for 'aplicacion' field on 'Prestacion' entity. The code posted before should return a NullPointerException in the next line:

```
System.out.println (app.getCodAplicacionV());
```

because 'app' entity is detached and lazy loading has been configured.

Why is not working lazy loading?

Thanks

Comment: try to add @Transactional on doSomething()

Comment: If getAplicacion() is called in a detached object it is supposed to raise the infamous LazyInitializationException. It's not... so app is still attached.

Comment: @Xstian - I've tried what you suggested (transactional persistence context) but I've got the same result.

Comment: @Ivan.aguirre - But it can not be attached as I'm using a transactional persistence context in the ejb so when the ejb method is finished, the persistence context is clear and all entities are detached. I've read this in all JPA books

Comment: I've read in internet that lazy links works with EclipseLink provider even when entities are detached. In such a case, EclipseLink will simply take a read-only connection from connection pool, execute loading and then put the connection back to pool. I've read this in the next link: http://softaria.com/2011/07/26/eclipselink-versus-hibernate/. But I would like to find this explanation in EclipseLink documentation.

Comment: @Eduardo Are you sure that your "transactionManager" configuration is well configured?

Comment: @Xstian I think so. How could I be sure? I've defined my Entity Manager with the annotation @PersistenceContext(name="DocuEjb",  type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
 private EntityManager em;

Comment: @Eduardo You can see here the official spring documentation. In any case, can you add your spring configurations, so that we can better help you. :)

Comment: I don't understand why your are talking about Spring is doing here when it seems to be plain old EJB injection ? And for Transactional, there is a JTA annotation for that: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html (well Spring use it, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Transactional on doSomething(), I think that your transaction manager is not well configured.

You can see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) the official spring documentation. In any case, can you add your spring configurations, so that we can better help you. :)

Comment: When you say @Transactional, do you mean @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) annotation? doSomething is a EJB method

Comment: My thought is that the transaction is closed when you try to get the relationship. I suggest you a behaviour like SpringTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the behavior your encounter is abnormal or your question should state it clearly:

- EJB are by default transactional
- Your JSF inject an EJB, with `@EJB`, and I guess JBoss can create a java reference and not a proxy
- The entity is being managed because the transaction is not done, it will finish when `doSomething` ends.

Your entity is then loaded into the `EntityManager`, and lazy loading works because there is a context to it.

You would call `em.evict(entity)` with the result your are getting, this would probably fails because the entity would not be managed any more.

Comment: I agree with you. But if you have a look to the code I've posted the lazy reference is being resolved once the 'doSomething' method has ended. And for this reason it should not resolve the lazy reference.

Comment: For instance, where is it being lazy loaded where it should not ? (because your example point to `doSomething`, not the real place where you use it). .

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've explained bad. The 'getResult' method is a EJB method, and because the persistence context type defined for the EJB is Transactional, the entity returned by the 'getResult' method should be detached. On the other hand, the 'doSomething' method is a managed bean method, and I think that the JEE container doesn't manage transactions for managed bean methods.

Comment: It is being lazy loaded where it should not in the next line: Aplicacion app = entity.getAplicacion();